# The term "other side" in French

Tags: demande-de-mot

What would be the French equivalent of "other side", when referring to it in a kind of philosophical way, not necessarily physical other side of the street, as in:

> On one side, I really want to reopen this question, on the other side ...

Like "the other side of the opinion".

Comment: Please specify context, abstract  "kind of philosophical way" is not a context and any answers we would give would be just as imprecise as what you're asking.

Comment: like "greener on the other side" = "(l'herbe ) verte ailleurs" or "other side of medal" = "l'envers de la médaille". I guess, these appears more philosophical...

Comment: Are you asking for the equivalent of *on the contrary* (*au contraire*)?

Answer (score 1):

Employé dans l'expression usuelle et aussi s'il est précédé en anglais par *on* :

- d'un autre coté
- D'un coté ... d'un autre coté

Précédé par *from* ou pour formuler une alternative inattendue parfois non induite par la première partie de la phrase :

- d'autre part
- D'une part ... d'autre part
- l'autre partie

Selon le contexte :

- sous l'autre angle
- d'un autre point de vue